# What happens If Olympic torch goes out accidentally?

Tags: olympics

What happens if the [Olympic torch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_flame) goes out accidentally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens If Olympic torch gets off accidentally?

In the same Wikipedia article you reference under the section "[Reigniting the flame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_flame#Reigniting_the_flame)"...

The Olympic torch is re-lit, or another torch is lit, from one of the multiple backup sources of the flame that is accompanying the relay.